# Why does file completion not work for git commands in the full version of Cmder?

Tags: git, cmder

I have been using Cmder for a while now.  I started with the mini version on a machine that had cygwin installed.  After changing jobs I decided to use the full version on my new work computer so that I can have access to various Unix utilities.  I have noticed that `<tab>` completing file names does not work with git commands such as `git add`.  Just to verify I removed Cmder and installed the mini version and sure enough file name completion works.  Is there a setting I can change to get autocompletion to work in the "full" version of Cmder?

Comment: same issue here. I dont need the version that includes git-for-windows, so I have just migrated to the mini version, after finding your post.